# How does Snap engage manage to integrate with Skype?

Tags: skype

They have a technology which allows them to connect with skype as a "friend" and then when there is an incoming chat on the website, it forwards that chat to the skype client.

I can't see anything in the skype API that allows this, how do they do it?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, companies like Snapengage and [ClickDesk](http://clickdesk.com) use Skype API to do this.